# Помогите вывести рандомное число ряда таблицы, не содержащие значения ряда другой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть 2 таблицы SQL. В одной таблице содержатся id людей, в другой таблице с id людей, которых функция рандома не должна вызвать. Как реализовать?
(PHP)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

Или

```
$banned = "SELECT id FROM table2";
$allowed = "SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (". $banned .")";
```

Но, вообще, нет смысла создавать для этого вторую таблицу, лучше в первой добавить, к примеру, поле `id_banned` и проверять его при выборе.